# OpenGL/GLSE alpha masking

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl

I'm implementing a paint app by using **OpenGL**/**GLSL**.
There is a feature where a user draws a "mask" by using brush with a pattern image, meantime the background changes according to the brush position. Take a look at the video to understand: [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0tvyxh7vyr3t9pp/screencast%202016-11-30%2000-37-48.mp4?dl=0)

I used CALayer's mask (iOS stuff) to achieve this effect (on the video). But this implementation is very costly, fps is pretty low. So I decided to use OpenGL for that.
For OpenGL implementation, I use the **Stencil** buffer for masking, i.e.:

```
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
// Draw mask (brush pattern)
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 255);
// Draw gradient background
// Display the buffer
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

The problem: **Stencil** buffer doesn't work with alpha, that's why I can't use semi-transparent patterns for the brushes.

The question: How can I achieve that effect from video by using **OpenGL**/**GLSL** but without **Stencil buffer**?

Comment: You say that the background changes. So you already have an appropriate background generated? If so, is the background defined as a fullscreen texture?

Comment: @MaticOblak , yes, I have an appropriate background generated for each draw iteration. I use shaders for the gradient generation, as input data, I use touches coordinates (the "begin" and "end" touches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your background is already generated (from comments) then you can simply use 2 textures in the shader to draw a each of the segments. You will need to redraw all of them until user lifts up his finger though.

So assume you have a texture that has a white footprint on it with alpha channel `footprintTextureID` and a background texture "backgroundTextureID". You need to bind both of a textures using `activeTexture` 1 and 2 and pass the 2 as uniforms in the shader.

Now in your vertex shader you will need to generate the relative texture coordinates from the position. There should be a line similar to `gl_Position = computedPosition;` so you need to add another `varying` value:

```
backgroundTextureCoordinates = vec2((computedPosition.x+1.0)*0.5, (computedPosition.y+1.0)*0.5);
```

or if you need to flip vertically

```
backgroundTextureCoordinates = vec2((computedPosition.x+1.0)*0.5, (-computedPosition.y+1.0)*0.5):
```

(The reason for this equation is that the output vertices are in interval `[-1,1]` but the textures use `[0,1]`: `[-1,1]+1 = [0,2]` then `[0,2]*0.5 = [0,1]`).

Ok so assuming you bound all of these correctly you now only need to multiply the colors in fragment shader to get the blended color:

```
uniform sampler2D footprintTexture;
varying lowp vec2 footprintTextureCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D backgroundTexture;
varying lowp vec2 backgroundTextureCoordinates;

void main() {
    lowp vec4 footprintColor = texture2D(footprintTexture, footprintTextureCoordinate);
    lowp vec4 backgroundColor = texture2D(backgroundTexture, backgroundTextureCoordinates);
    gl_FragColor = footprintColor*backgroundColor;
}
```

If you wanted you could multiply with alpha value from the footprint but that only loses the flexibility. Until the footprint texture is white it makes no difference so it is your choice.

Comment: hey. Thanks for this advice, I think that gonna work for me. Will try it today.

Comment: hey, this solution is working, thanks! But I've faced new problem - I'm not sure what is right way to clear a texture. Do you how to do that?
Basically I use FBO to draw into textures. To clear this texture, should I clear this FBO or should I directly clear a texture?

Comment: Well when the texture is attached as color buffer to the frame buffer you can use it as any other color buffers. So simply calling glClear should clear the texture to a specific color you have previously set. Just ensure the correct frame buffer is bound when you call it. There are other ways such as you could call text sub image to send new data to the texture but this one is quite heavy on performance to only clear it. Another is to simply draw a rectangle over the whole texture which again seems an overkill.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I already have solved that. glClear wasn't working for my case, so I had to use shaders. Also, I've marked this answer as "accepted". And thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Stencil is a boolean on/off test, so as you say it can't cope with alpha.

The only GL technique which works with alpha is the blending, but due to the color change between frames you can't simply flatten this into a single layer in a single pass.

To my mind it sounds like you need to maintain multiple independent layers in off-screen buffers, and then blend them together per frame to form what is shown on screen. This gives you complete independence for how you update each layer per frame.

Comment: It is something I was thinking. You could actually create a FBO which would draw the background color using color mask to disable the alpha and then draw the images using alpha channel only. But I would say the issue here is what happens when a single path crosses itself? I would expect that if you create a circle then the first (bottom) image would be red while the last (top) that is overlapping the first one will be green. But this is in conflict with using the background approach...

Comment: Even if doing so it is then easier to have the background texture only (which changes when dragging) and then use a shader with 2 textures (the footprint image and the background one) then manipulate the background texture coordinates to correspond to the background texture position. This way no FBO is needed at all.

Comment: Yeah, good call. I was thinking about two independent off-screen buffers too. Btw, I've not tried to blend buffers before, so can you give me any advice on it? For example there are two off-screen buffers: **A** - buffer with brush strokes, **B** - background buffer? How to blend and draw these two?

Comment: Well in your case you will need to use 2 textures. Each of the FBO needs an attached texture (the render buffer is not even needed). Then use active texture to be able to assign both of the textures at the same time and pass them to the shaders. If you ensure that the FBOs have the same dimensions as the main buffer you can use GL_NEAREST parameter on the texture to gain performance. But there might be a bit more work if you need the POT textures; use the first POT dimensions that are larger then the buffer and then use a viewport of the target buffer size. Then adjust the texture coordinates.